# Фоновые службы в Unity

Tags: java, c#, unity3d, службы

Сейчас появилась потребность в реализации следующего: знать сколько именно отсутствовал пользователь в приложении и в зависимости от этого менять какие то переменные при его заходе в приложение. Для отслеживания времени инактива, как я понял, можно использовать фоновые службы Androida и у них для реализации этого свои библиотеки на Яве. После поиска инфы голова готова превратиться в кусок желе, поэтому хотел спросить тут. Есть ли готовые решения(для Юнити) того, что способно работать даже тогда, когда приложение не открыто? И если есть на памяти статьи с укомплектованной инфой по службам, то покидайте плиз. Кроме Unity и С# пока ни на чём не работал.

Comment: А не проще и надежнее при паузе `OnApplicationPause(true)` и/или закрытии приложения `OnApplicationQuit` сохранять текущее время, а при возвращении в игру вычислять длительность отсутствия и выполнять соответствующие действия?

Comment: Я рассматривал этот вариант, но он мне показался уж больно странным и каким то не верным что ли. Неужели именно такое решение общепринято в таких ситуациях? Ну не знаю, не знаю.. Но, если ничего не найду, то реализовать попробую именно так

Comment: Конечно правильней будет как сказал  Александр Даниловский. Служба -не стабильна и может быть остановлена, будет жрать память и батарею - и ради чего? Что бы выполнить две операции - записать время закрытия и открытия. Действительно, что бы импортировать java-код в юнити придется поработать, и это решение не будет работать на других платформах. Так что правильно будет это делать при открытии и при закрытии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам год назад столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Нашёл следующее решение. При запуске:

```
public string TimeCompare;
TimeCompare = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Time");
TimeFromLastLoad = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(TimeCompare);
```

При закрытии:

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}

private void OnApplicationPause()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Если в Вашем коде под `OnApplicationPause` подразумевается метод из класса `MonoBehavior`, то Вы пропустили [булевый аргумент](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Примерно таким образом и вышел из ситуации

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Да, действительно, совсем про него забыл.